# Disable zoom function in tablet

Tags: android, screen, zooming, tablet

Now I have created an apps in tablet which fit the screen size but there are button at the right bottom corner which can choose either stretch to fill screen or zoom to fill screen. I want to disable the function either hide that button or won't change anything after pressing anything

I have tried to trigger the keyevent of that button but there is no related keycode.

anyone can help?

Comment: I have solved this problem.
I just need to add  android:targetSdkVersion="11" and that button disappear.Thanks all.

Answer (score 4):

To disable that function your app has to support xlarge screens. You can set this in your manifest:

```
<supports-screens android:xlargeScreens="true" />
```

Comment: I have tried this method but it said "No resource identifier found for attribute 'xlargeScreens' in package "

Comment: You have to increase the target API and build against a newer sdk which supports that tag

Comment: Thanks.If I want to support both the old one and new one ?

Comment: You can use a higher sdk and set minimum still to the needed sdk version

Answer (score 0):

This can help you to disable that function:

```
<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="false"
    android:largeScreens="false"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:resizeable="false"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="false" />
```

Comment: with this configuration in your manifest you are excluding large range of Android devices from seeing your app in Google Plat, I would not recommend to do it